Can't understand expected gain calculation in first price auction
I'm reading this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-price_sealed-bid_auction#Example
What it says: Suppose there are two bidders A and B, whose valuations (for some item being bid on) are $a$ and $b$ drawn from a continuous uniform random distribution over $[0,1]$. Then it is a Bayesian Nash Equilibrium if they bid $a/2$ and $b/2$ respectively.
Proof: We assume A knows that B bids $f(b)=b/2$, but A does not know the value of $b$. Suppose $A$ bids $x$. Then there are two cases:

$x\geq f(b)$. Then A wins with a net gain of $a-x$. This happens with probability $f^{-1}(x)=2x$


I didn't understand this last statement about the probability. $x$ is a uniform random variable between $0$ and $1$. Can't we just say that A loses with probability $P(f(x)<f(b))=P(x<f^{-1}(f(b)))=b$, so that her winning probability would be $1-b$? Where did $f^{-1}(x)$ come from?

In the statement OP mentioned,
$x$ is seen as fixed and $b$ is seen as a random variable (note the sentence "A does not know the value of $b$").
Hence, $x \geq f(b)$ happens with probability
$$
\Pr[f(b) \leq x] = \Pr[0 \leq b \leq f^{-1}(x)] = f^{-1}(x).
$$
